# codeigniter pagination disable query string

Tags: codeigniter, pagination

I can't disable the query strings in my links! Please help.

```
$this->load->library('pagination');

$config['base_url'] = base_url() . 'exhibition/large_artwork_list/';
$config['uri_segment'] = 3;
$config['total_rows'] = '200';
$config['per_page'] = '20'; 
$config['full_tag_open'] = '<div id="pagination" style="float: left;">';
$config['full_tag_close'] = '</div>'; 

$this->pagination->initialize($config); 

echo $this->pagination->create_links();
```

links end up like this

```
http://site.dev/exhibition/large_artwork_list/&per_page=20
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

global config was overwriting it. in config.php `$config['enable_query_strings'] = TRUE;`

Answer (score 0):

Have you look @ the user guide?

`$config['page_query_string'] = FALSE`

Its all there:

https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/pagination.html

Comment: yeah, that not working for me. besides according to the user guide it defaults to false.